# How to delete inscription "LaTeX Tikzposter" in the low right corner?

Tags: tikzposter

How to manage?

```
 \documentclass[25pt, a1papper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering dsfds sdfsfd}}
\author{fdssfa}
\date{\today}
\institute{fsdfs sdfdsfds}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment}
\usetheme{Desert}

\defineblockstyle{MyBlock}{% define a custom style for a block
    titlewidthscale=0.8, bodywidthscale=1, titlecenter,
    titleoffsetx=0pt, titleoffsety=0pt, bodyoffsetx=0pt, bodyoffsety=15mm,
    bodyverticalshift=15mm, roundedcorners=22, linewidth=5pt,
    titleinnersep=8mm, bodyinnersep=8mm
}{
    \draw[rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners, inner sep=\blockbodyinnersep,
          line width=\blocklinewidth, color=black,
          top color=titlebgcolor!90, bottom color=titlebgcolor!20!white,
          %fill=blockbodybgcolor
          ]
      (blockbody.south west) rectangle (blockbody.north east); %
    \ifBlockHasTitle%
        \draw[rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners, inner sep=\blocktitleinnersep,
          top color=titlebgcolor!90, bottom color=titlebgcolor!20!white,
          line width=\blocklinewidth, color=black, %fill=blocktitlebgcolor
          ]
      (blocktitle.south west) rectangle (blocktitle.north east); %
    \fi%
}
\newcommand\myblock[3][MyBlock]{\useblockstyle{#1}\block{#2}{#3}\useblockstyle{Basic}}



\begin{document}
\useblockstyle{Basic}

\maketitle

\block{Introduction}
{
    \blindtext
}


\begin{columns}
    \column{0.4}
    \myblock{Objectives}{% use custom block to define the objectives
      \blindtext \vspace{2cm}
     }

    \column{0.6}{
    \block{Something else}{Here, \blindtext \vspace{4cm}}
    \note[
        targetoffsetx=-9cm,
        targetoffsety=-6.5cm,
        width=0.5\linewidth
        ]
        {e-mail \texttt{sharelatex@sharelatex.com}}}
\end{columns}

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5}
    \block{A figure}
    {
        \begin{tikzfigure}

        \end{tikzfigure}
    }
    \column{0.5}
    \block{Description of the figure}{\blindtext}
\end{columns}
\block[titleleft,titleoffsetx=2em,titleoffsety=1em,bodyoffsetx=2em,
bodyoffsety=1em,titlewidthscale=.6, bodywidthscale=.8, roundedcorners=14,
linewidth=8mm, bodyinnersep=4em, titleinnersep=2em]
{Sample Block}{Text\\Text\\Text Text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff` shall do. `texdoc tikzposter` on page 4.

Comment: Please always read the manual first, write a bit more than "How to manage?" and try to reduce your sample code as much as possible. In this case `\documentclass{tikzposter}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}` wouldn't have needed to browse your code for some graphics or alike. Just some advice for future postings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The author provided some handy and short command for this. Maybe you should consider in leaving the logo as it is nice advertisement for that project. 
But here you are:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{tikzposter}
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff

\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

The command can be found on page 4 of the current documentation.

Comment: Do you know any way to move it to the left-bottom corner?

Comment: @xuhdev Quick but not nice solution. Find your `tikzposter.dtx` file, search for the line `\node[inner sep=4pt, anchor=south east, fill=white, draw=none, rounded corners=5, fill opacity=0.3, text opacity=1]` and change "south east" to "south west". It would be nicer to patch this. Search this page on how to or ask a new question.